# How to install the Pyinstaller on Win 7

Tags: python, windows-7, pyinstaller

I am using win7 to install the PyInstaller.

I have tried the method accroding to ([How to install PyInstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767010/how-to-install-pyinstaller/11913113#11913113)  )but I failed and there is the log,is there anything wrong?

```
C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller>python Configure.py
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "Configure.py", line 28, in <module>
    from PyInstaller import HOMEPATH, PLATFORM

ImportError: No module named PyInstaller
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the system properties and go to the environment variables and set the PATH to the address of where the pyinstaller is located.