# Python, pygame, py2exe

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

I can't make this .py .exe help me.
i have python34 installed on windows 7 - 32 bits

This is a Snake.py simple game and i can't convert it using py2exe.
i looked in google and stackoverflow and everywhere else but couldn't fix it.
i get this error when trying to convert the script.

The error: http://pastebin.com/uRHpg1B8

And this is my game: http://pastebin.com/R6A89Nhe

Comment: did you try pyinstaller

Comment: nop, i'm new in this python stuff

Comment: Why my bitdefender total security is blocking me from downloading pyinstaller??? it pop up  a warning window saying this is a trojan!!! lol

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767010/how-to-install-pyinstaller) and learn how to convert to exe using pyinstaller in from google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on your error output, it looks like you are missing several packages which are important for `pygame` to function. Error output duplicated below, for future reference.

```
  8 missing Modules
  ------------------
? MacOS                               imported from pygame.macosx
? Numeric                             imported from pygame
? OpenGL                              imported from pygame
? Py25Queue                           imported from pygame.threads
? Queue                               imported from pygame.threads
? numpy                               imported from pygame, pygame._numpysndarra
y, pygame._numpysurfarray
? packaging                           imported from pkg_resources
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
```

Comment: How do i fix that please?

Comment: Well, it's possible that the application uses the MacOS module to check whether its on a Mac, or something.

Comment: To clear up these errors though, the first thing you need to do is install these python packages. Numeric, OpenGL, and numpy are ones that I recognize. They're definitely useful for games.

Comment: I don't thik so, there is no code like that in my game!

Comment: This issue is *not* with *your* code. It's because of code that you don't have, but that you need. Take out the `import pygame` line and other imports, and you will not get the same errors. (then, the problem *would* be in your code.)

Comment: Aaah ok i got it, now i'm always disabling some services in my computer, so the pip command is not working hahaha i have to restart my computer, but i'm really really lazy to wait lmao, does it make any sense to you?
Thanks man i really appreciate your help, i will check for that and keep you updated!

Comment: Lol. No problem. I wasn't very clear in my answer, I know. Mainly because I haven't used Python in a while... good luck! :-)

Comment: Hi man i got a problem, i installed numpy using .exe
and for OpenGL i couldn't find .exe, i found .rar and after doing setup.py install i get errors...
so i went to pip and did:
pip install OpenGL

Comment: I got this error

Collecting OpenGL
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02B8FEF0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/opengl/

Even if i try to upgrade pip!!!

Comment: It looks like several things are going on there. I recommend asking this as a separate question, possibly on [su].