# How to convert python script to exe Without additional files

Tags: python, file, exe

I want to convert my python script to exe without additional files like ddl, pyd.. 
Is it possible?

Comment: What script? What have you tried? What happened?

Comment: Windows platform? Maybe try google - one program 've used is py2exe - http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: You can use pyinstaller To install : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21000866/6833134 How to use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34454262/6833134

Answer (score 1):

Use pyinstaller https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller
Install it by running `pip install pyinstaller` in terminal / console
Then run `pyinstaller --onefile yourscriptsname.py` and it will create you an exe file in the same directory